# Square matrix 0 x 0?

Tags: matrix-calculus, dynamic-programming

Can you consider a 0x0 matrix as a square matrix, I can't find the precise definition. I need it for my programming assignment for throwing exceptions.

Comment: I'ld call it $\emptyset$.  Isn't that a sort of NaN?

Comment: I mean... sure... it represents the unique linear transformation from $\Bbb R^0$ to $\Bbb R^0$.  There is no question about the existence of that function... it is the function $f~:~\{0\}\to\{0\}$ given by $0\mapsto 0$.  It's determinant would be equal to $1$ (*as it would be the empty-product*).

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: Are you deliberately trying to sow confusion?

Comment: Personally, I expect there to be some authors who explicitly allow for $0\times 0$ matrices and other authors who explicitly disallow them, very similarly to how in graph theory one might explicitly not consider the [null graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_graph) to be a graph or how one might explicitly require a field to have $0\neq 1$.  The end result is that these sort of mathematical objects on zero dimensions are particularly uninteresting and problematic when phrasing theorems correctly, so they are often excluded.

Comment: See also [Zero object (algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_object_(algebra)) as well as [Field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element).

Comment: @TonyK Not at all; the accepted answer is quite the same, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it is specifically mentioned in the statement of the assignment, I would say that it's up to you. If I were given this project, I would disallow it and throw an exception. An alternative approach is to  make it depend on a compile-time flag (`#define ZERO_DIMENSIONS_ALLOWED 0` or `#define ZERO_DIMENSIONS_ALLOWED 1`). The important thing is that whatever you decide, you document it when you submit your project.

Answer (score 2):

It's more or less up to you if you want to bother with zero-size matrices. I will name a few trivial properties of a 0×0 matrix.

There is only one matrix in $\Bbb{R}^{0×0}$: It's $[]$. They can be added, multiplied, each time you get $[]$. It has an inverse, it is also $[]$. Its determinant is 1 because the product of empty sequence is 1 and there is only the empty permutation. The rank of [] is 0 so it is a regular matrix. It is also the identity matrix. It can be multiplied only with matrices which have either zero width or zero length. [] has no eigen-velues. Its trace is 0 because there are no elements on the diagonal and an empty sum is 0.

You can also define $\Bbb{R}^{n×0}$ and $\Bbb{R}^{0×n}$ matrices, these sets of matrices also have only one element each.

Comment: Your last paragraph is confusing: such matrices have zero elements, not one. It's the _set_ of such matrices that has one element.

Comment: I formulated it wrongly, I meant the sets of matrices, not the matrices themselves.